# Job with ShouldBeUnique never dispatched

Tags: php, laravel, jobs

I'm trying to dispatch a job which implements `shouldBeUnique` but it doesn't work, my job is never in the queue. If I remove ShouldBeUnique, it works as expected.

I am using Redis.

Do you guys have an idea what's happening?

Here is my code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Exception;
use Throwable;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class VerifyJob implements ShouldQueue, ShouldBeUnique
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $releaseDelay = 10;
    public $tries = 3;

    public $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function uniqueId()
    {
        return $this->user->id;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        \Log::debug('verify 0');

        return;
    }

    public function failed(Throwable $exception)
    {
        \Log::debug('verify 999');
    }
}
```

Comment: I would guess there's already a job in the queue. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#unique-job-locks "Behind the scenes, when a ShouldBeUnique job is dispatched, Laravel attempts to acquire a lock with the uniqueId key. If the lock is not acquired, the job is not dispatched." Try changing your `uniqueId` function to set a *different* unique ID (add a random string, for example) and see if it dispatches.

Comment: you can set   the time for it to be unique 
public $uniqueFor = 3600;

Comment: There is no job in the queue. I do `php artisan horizon:clear` to remove all jobs in the queue.
EDIT: I updated the `uniqueId` and it worked. Why? Of course I have failed jobs etc, but it seems we can dispatch again an event right after it's been completed, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks to [ceejayoz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66636630/job-with-shouldbeunique-never-dispatched#comment117796052_66636630), I have to use another uniqueId. Why, I don't know but it worked.

Answer (score 6):

It's because laravel failed to unlock the unique id, and that is why it was able to dispatch again after you use another unique id.

the reason is the file laravel uses to store the unique id doesn't have right permissions. laravel needs to delete it to unlock the id. It's under the storage/framework/cache/data diretory

Comment: After hours of frustration, it was the cache stored in the location you specified.

I managed to resolve this with: php artisan cache:clear