# Laravel scheduler executes the wrong job

Tags: laravel, redis, scheduled-tasks

I have some schedules in my Kernel and they will be executed as schedule:

```php
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule): void
{
    $schedule->job(new PdnsSync())
        ->everyTenMinutes()
        ->onOneServer();


     $schedule->job(new DismissRiskyUsersScheduler)
         ->everyFiveMinutes()
         ->onOneServer();

     // many more...
}
```

Due too some planed maintenance, I had to stop the queue workers (about 20 containers) for some time. After bringing them back online, the PdnsSync job will be queued correctly but it executes the `DismissRiskyUsersScheduler`.

I found this behaviour by enable telescope, go to the scheduler, click on the `PdnsSync` command an follow the jobs:

[image: telegram/scheduler]

Jobs from the scheduled command:

[image: telescope/jobs]

- queue-connection is redis
- laravel version 10
- php 8.2

I've tried:

```
php artisan optimize:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

- restarted all containers (front-end and workers)
- restarted redis

Because the question was asked if the PdnsSync class is realy calling the correct jobs, here the class:

```php
class PdnsSync implements ShouldQueue, ShouldBeUnique
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    const CHUNK = 10;

    protected array $jobs = [
        LhgTenantJob::class,
        AviatarTenantJob::class
    ];

    public function handle(): void
    {
        $jobs = $this->getJobs();

        if (empty($jobs)) {
            return;
        }

        if (count($jobs) > self::CHUNK) {
            $jobs = array_chunk($jobs, self::CHUNK);
        }

        Bus::batch([$jobs])
            ->name('pdns')
            ->dispatch();
    }

    protected function getJobs(): array
    {
        foreach ($this->jobs as $job) {
            $jobs[] = new $job;
        }

        return $jobs ?? [];
    }
}
```

### Update

I've changed the `PdnsSync` job to run in a dedicated queue called `pdns`. I also added the queue to the workers using the `php artisan queue:work --queue=default,pdns` command.

`php artisan schedule:list` shows all the schedules as expected:

```
# truncated list
*/10 * * * *  App\Jobs\PdnsSync ............ Next Due: xxx minutes from now
# ...other schedules
```

running the PdnsSync schedule manually via `php artisan schedule:test`, still not executing the job.

`php artisan queue:monitor redis:default,pdns`

```
  Queue name ......................................... Size / Status
  [redis] default ........................................... [0] OK
  [redis] pdns .............................................. [0] OK
```

In addition, telescope does even not showing any jobs in relation to the scheduled task:

[image: telescope/pdns_3]

##### To summarize this:

All scheduled task/commands work fine except the `PdnsSync` which did before and I run out of ideas.

### Update

I've renamed the class from  `App\Jobs\PdnsSync` to `App\Jobs\PrivateDnsUpdate`. Now the jobs run as they should. I would like to understand this in depth.

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: and clearly you are not dispatching DismissRiskyUsersScheduler from PdnsSync, right?

Comment: yes, thats absolutely verified. There were noch changes on the code. I suspect some sort of cacheing thing..

Comment: The question I am going to reference here is closed, but seems closely related to the explanation you've given in your self-answer and might therefore be a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66636630/job-with-shouldbeunique-never-dispatched

Comment: That sounds very close @geertjanknapen. I unterstand the effect in general, but it's unclear why this worked before or at which stage laravel where unable to unlock the job. I use redis cache and killed the entire cache to make sure that nothing is in. Anyhow, I'll reconsider the concept of the `PdnsSync` process. Thanks for your hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've removed the `ShouldBeUnique` interface in the `Pdns` Class, which resolved the problem.

Before

```php
class PdnsSync implements ShouldQueue, ShouldBeUnique
```

After

```php
class PdnsSync implements ShouldQueue
```

However, I don't understand (yet) why this worked before but not after the maintenance.

Comment: One explanation might be as follows. `ShouldBeUnique` makes sure that no other instance of the same job is dispatched if another instance is already on the queue and not finished processing. So perhaps there is a (failed) instance of the job on the queue somewhere that has not finished, therefore not creating new jobs.

Comment: Thats what I guessed too but by calling `queue:flush`, `queue:clear` they should be gone, shouldn't they?

Comment: Well yes, but I've noticed that whenever I use redis, it does not actually seem to clear the queue. I don't know why this is (or if this is the case for you), I haven't researched it. We are running everything using docker though, so this whole comment might not even apply.

Comment: Thats why I'm so scared about it. We run everything on k8s, also redis. I killed the entire redis cluster. So there where nothing there anymore. My learning for this is: never use the `ShouldBeUnique` interface in the task scheduler.

Comment: You'd imagine something like that would be supported.. Good luck though, lord knows I need it :)